# How to get mouse is over shape on canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have a canvas where user can select things on images by drawing shape around it. So there might be more than one shape on canvas

Now what I want is when mouseover shape I want to change opacity of canvas except custom shape(where mouse over is).

It is like reverse area effect that some jQuery plugin doing 
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html (reverse effect here)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you need to go with a data model approach to Canvas. Basically, you need to store the information that will appear on the canvas. Then, you have a function which renders the canvas using that information.

When a user moves their mouse over the canvas, you determine their x,y relative to the canvas, look at your data and see what is at x, y. Alter the state in your data and re-build the canvas.

Here is a very crude example I quickly threw together. I would highly recommend structuring your javascript better, but this is a proof of concept. In practice you will want to store your data in an indexed format, and do the mousemove() function call better because it gets hammered as a user moves their mouse (usually done with `setTimeout` and ignoring subsequent calls).

```
$(function() {
    function renderCanvas() {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {              
          context.fillRect(data[i].x, data[i].y, data[i].width, data[i].height);
        }        
    }

    var context = $(".myCanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");

    var data = [];

    data.push({ x : 25, y : 25, height : 100, width : 100 });

    renderCanvas();

    $(".myCanvas").mousemove(function(e) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (e.pageX > data[i].x && e.pageX < data[i].x + data[i].width && e.pageY > data[i].y && e.pageY < data[i].y + data[i].height) {
               data[i].height = 200;
               renderCanvas();
            }                        
        }
    });
});
```

In fiddle format: http://jsfiddle.net/wUnDu/1/

Comment: does this method works for custom shapes? How to store canvas information to look for?

Comment: Yea it could support custom shapes. As long as you have some algorithm to determine if pixel X,Y is inside your shape. It could get to be some pretty complicated Math depending on the vertices of your shape, and in most use cases shapes can be simplified down behind the scenes. That's the nature of canvas though which is very similar to traditional screen buffer programming. Here is an example of some algorithms you could use - http://www.quora.com/Algorithms/What-are-the-algorithms-for-determining-if-a-point-is-inside-an-arbitrary-closed-shape-or-not raycasting in particular seems viable.